# p5.js | Quality of image captured from camera feed, lower than actual camera feed?

Tags: javascript, video, p5.js

With the code below, the quality of the video coming from my Mac's camera and shown inside `<video>` is great.

However the quality of the frame I capture and show in p5's canvas is pretty low, dark and grainy. Why is that and can I fix it ?

```
function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(canvasSize, canvasSize)
  canvas.elt.width = canvasSize
  canvas.elt.height = canvasSize
  video = createCapture(VIDEO)
}

let PAUSE = false

async function draw() {

  if (video && video.loadedmetadata) {

    if (!PAUSE) {
      // the quality of this image is much lower than what is shown inside p5's <video>
      image(video.get(), 0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize, x, y, canvasSize, canvasSize)

      PAUSE = true

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was.

It was not due to me setting the `canvas.elt.width` and `canvas.elt.height`, even though setting them is indeed redundant.

It's because in the code shown in the OP I was capturing the **very first frame** and this is **too soon** so the very first frame is still dark and blurry. Apparently the first few frames coming from the camera are like that.

If I give my code a delay of e.g. 5 seconds the frame it captures is then the exact same quality as the one coming from the video feed.

```
let video
let canvasWidth = 400

// set this to 10 on https://editor.p5js.org/ and you'll see the problem
const DELAY = 5000

function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(canvasWidth, canvasWidth)
  canvas.elt.width = canvasWidth // redundant
  canvas.elt.height = canvasWidth // redundant
  video = createCapture(VIDEO)
}

let PAUSE = false
let start = Date.now()

async function draw() {
  let delay = Date.now() - start

  if (video && video.loadedmetadata) {

    if (delay > DELAY && !PAUSE) {
      PAUSE = true
      
      let x = Math.round((video.width / 2) - (canvasWidth / 2))
      let y = Math.round((video.height / 2) - (canvasWidth / 2))

      // the quality of this image is now perfect
      image(video.get(), 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasWidth, x, y, canvasWidth, canvasWidth)
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be setting width/height this way. That will mess up the sizing on high DPI displays and cause your image to appear stretched and blurry.

```
const canvasSize = 500;

function setup() {
  let canvas = createCanvas(canvasSize, canvasSize)
  // Don't do this, it will mess up the sizing on high DPI displays:
  // canvas.elt.width = canvasSize
  // canvas.elt.height = canvasSize
  video = createCapture(VIDEO)
}

let PAUSE = false;

function draw() {
  if (video && video.loadedmetadata) {
    if (!PAUSE) {
      // the quality of this image is much lower than what is shown inside p5's <video>
      image(video.get(), 0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize, 0, 0, canvasSize, canvasSize)
    }
  }
}

function keyPressed() {
  if (key === 'p') {
    PAUSE = !PAUSE;
  }
}
```

With this code I paused the video that was being rendered to p5.js and then took a screenshot. The version of the video displayed on the p5.js canvas wash indistinguishable from the live video.